# How to write to a log file?

Tags: file, logging, progress-4gl

```
input from cust.txt.
define temp-table tt-cust field name like customer.name
                       field custnum like customer.custnum.
repeat:
   create ttcust.
   import delimiter "," tt-cust.name tt-cust.custnum.
end.
input close.
for each customer where customer.country = "usa" exclusive-lock:
   assign customer.name = tt-cust.name
          customer.custnum = tt-cust.custnum.
end.
```

I want to write errors in a log-file if the data in a input file is wrong. For instance if there is a character and not a number in the custnum field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use streams to handle both input and output at the same time.

```
DEFINE STREAM inStream.
DEFINE STREAM outStream.

DEFINE VARIABLE iTestInt AS INT64     NO-UNDO.

INPUT STREAM inStream FROM cust.txt.

/* Add error log */
OUTPUT STREAM outStream TO c:\temp\errlog.txt.
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE tt-cust 
    FIELD name LIKE customer.name
    FIELD custnum LIKE customer.custnum.
REPEAT:
   CREATE tt-cust.
   IMPORT STREAM inStream DELIMITER "," tt-cust.name tt-cust.custnum.

   /* Test if custnum is a number */   
   iTestInt = INT64(TT-CUST.custnum) NO-ERROR.
   IF iTestInt = ? THEN DO:
       PUT STREAM outStream UNFORMATTED "Strange custnum: " + tt-cust.custnum SKIP.
       NEXT.
   END.

END.
INPUT STREAM inStream CLOSE.
OUTPUT STREAM outStream CLOSE.
```